# How can I receive the submitted data in a contact form into my own private email

Tags: laravel

I have called in Laravel's Mail inside my Controller like this:

```
    \Mail::to($candidate)->send(new EmailVerification($candidate));
    return view('/formsubmit');
```

The data received in the form are name, email, job_title, dob and interests. Is there a way I can receive the information entered by the user inside another email address?

Comment: You can cc or bcc the other email addresses.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mail#sending-mail), you can add cc and bcc.

```
Mail::to($candidate)
->cc($moreUsers)
->bcc($evenMoreUsers)
->send(new EmailVerification($candidate));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to get the name, email, job_title, date of birth and interests of candidates in my own email after they have received a link to verify their email. Like have their information in my email just like it is in the database. Is it possible?

Comment: @cd4success of course that is possible,  you can do something like `->cc(['your-email@example.com','some-other-email@example.com'])`

Comment: I have used the code above but I'm not receiving the information submitted in the form inside my gmail account: ***```Mail::to($candidate)
->cc(forshine56@gmail.com)
->send(new EmailVerification($candidate));```***. Only receiving the verification links.

Comment: @cd4success it looks like you just have the links in your email, in this case it will send the same email to your email too, if you want to receive a different email you can use the same method and create another email template with the data that you want to recieve and send it to yourself once send method returns true.

Comment: I'm still not getting anything yet. Only the verification link. ***```         \Mail::to('cd4successreal@yahoo.com')->cc('forshine56@gmail.com')->send(new CandidateInformation($client));***. I declared this right after the first code I gave you above. The CandidateInformation is a Mailable class with it's own separate view for the email I was which contains blade directives to parse the data. What do I do now?
```